# How to run 2 process and exchange input/output between them multiple times?

Tags: dart, process

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Future<String> getOutAndAnswer(testcase) async {
  Process python = await Process.start('python', ['tasks/histogram/run.py']);

  Process java = await Process.start('java', ['solutions/Histogram.java']);

  String results = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < testcase; i++){
    final String out = await python.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).first;

    java.stdin.writeln(out);

    final String answer = await java.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).first;

    python.stdin.writeln(answer);

    results += "($out, $answer)";
  }

  return results;
}
```

Basically, the python program is responsible for generating the input of each test case, then the java program will take the input and return the answer, which is sent to the python program to check if it's correct or not, and so on for every test case.

But when I try to use the above code I get an error saying I've already listened to the stream once:

```
Exception has occurred.
StateError (Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.)
```

Python program:

```
import os

CASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "cases")

test_cases = next(os.walk(CASE_DIR))[2]

print(len(test_cases))
for case in sorted(test_cases):
    with open(os.path.join(CASE_DIR, case), 'r') as f:
        print(f.readline(), end='', flush=True)
        f.readline()
        
        expected_output = f.readline()

        user_output = input()
        
        if expected_output != user_output:
            raise ValueError("Wrong answer!")

print("EXIT", flush=True)
```

Java program:

```
public class Histogram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int t = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            String answer = calculateAnswer(input);

            System.out.println(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only running the python and java processes once, and then trying to read their stdout stream multiple times. Maybe the processes should be inside the for loop so that they are run with every iteration of the loop.

Comment: But if I do that I'll keep running the first test case only. Because won't that be like restarting the process every time?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see what the java and python programs were or what their output looks like. Its difficult to guess at what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: Added the programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with `.first` which is going to listen to the stream, get the first element, and then immediately stop listening to the stream. See the documentation here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-async/Stream/first.html

You should instead listen once and define an `onData` method to perform the steps. See the documentation for `.listen()` here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-async/Stream/listen.html